# cannot connect to local CodeIgniter database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m pretty new to CodeIgniter and php. I have this issue which I can’t figure out.

I am trying to start working on a CodeIgniter php site and I keep getting:
Class 'DB' not found

I have an error on line 92 this is the line

```
try {
            DB::connect(DB_ADAPTER, array(
              'host'    => DB_HOST,
              'user'    => DB_USER,
              'pass'    => DB_PASS,
              'name'    => DB_NAME,
              'persist' => DB_PERSIST
            )); // connect
            if (defined('DB_CHARSET') && trim(DB_CHARSET)) {
              DB::execute("SET NAMES ?", DB_CHARSET);
            } // if
            DB::execute('ROLLBACK');
            DB::execute('UNLOCK TABLES');
            DB::execute('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1');

          } catch(Exception $e) {
            if (Env::isDebugging()) {
              Env::dumpError($e);
            } else {
              Logger::log($e, Logger::FATAL);
              Env::executeAction('error', 'db_connect');
            } // if
          } // try
```

Comment: this is a problem in the code, it has nothing to do with the database server / connection.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/

Comment: do you have an idea  where i should look ? The web site dose work on line it not working on my localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use this method. Go to your `applications -> config -> database.php` and enter in your database credentials there.

Then head to `applications -> config -> autoload.php` and in the `libraries` array add `database` eg:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

(Should be around line 55).

Then, you can use the [database guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/) and Codeigniter's built in database helper to do what you want.

You want to do all of these in your `model`. E.g:

```
function madeup_stuff($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where("table_name", array("id" => $id));
    $data = array();
    foreach ($query as $q){
        $data[] = $q;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have applications -> config folder i have rtunk-> config i added  define('DB_ADAPTER', 'mysql');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'crm');
    define('DB_PREFIX', '');
    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
    define('DB_PERSIST', 'false');
    return true;

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of codeigniter? @user3041833

Comment: it is not my project i just need to make some changes on existing  project were the vershen is written?